# How to add placeholder to joomla contact form

Tags: php, joomla

I am designing a template, however, I want my contact form to have placeholders. I tried overriding the contact component form file `components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default_form.php` but it seems to use joomla `JForm` or something that doesn't give me the ability to add placeholder directly.

```
$this->form->getInput('contact_name');
$this->form->getInput('contact_email');
...
```

How can I add placeholde to the contacts? I definitely don't want to replace those pieces of code with naive html code. Neither I want to add a javascript code to do that (I know it's hard but I want it to be done using Joomla core).

Answer (score 1):

You can add `hint="Placeholder name"` in `components/com_contact/models/forms/contact.xml`

```
<field
    name="contact_name"
    type="text"
    label="COM_CONTACT_CONTACT_EMAIL_NAME_LABEL"
    description="COM_CONTACT_CONTACT_EMAIL_NAME_DESC"
    id="contact-name"
    size="30"
    filter="string"
    required="true"
    hint="Placeholder name"
/>
```